# Fetch JSONObject instead of JSONArray for single row of data in MySQL Database using PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a few queries that I'm executing in my Android app. Each will only return one row of data, so I'd like to treat the output as JSONObjects rather than JSONArrays since they would be just be arrays with single objects inside; kind of pointless in my view.

As of now my PHP looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT moveCount FROM Chessmates.Board_States WHERE Games_GameID = 2;";
$sth = mysqli_query($con, $query);




if(mysqli_errno()) {
    echo "error";
} else {
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sth, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
        //var_dump($r);
    }


    echo json_encode($rows);
}
```

and the output looks like this:

```
[{"moveCount":"0"}]
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
{"moveCount":"0"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only returning one row of data, then you don't need to make an array.

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sth, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $rows = $r;
}
```

You get the data as you did because you were creating an *array* of *objects*, But since you're only going to ever get one result (*as you stated*), you can simple set it up as a variable.